# How to compile Urho3D's submodule for HoloLens

Tags: hololens, urhosharp, urho3d

There is a readme [here](https://github.com/xamarin/urho/blob/master/README.md)

But it doesn't cover compilation of the submodule for HoloLens.

The developer lists these steps (from various posts [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79820/urhosharp-forms-on-uwp-unable-to-load-dll-mono-urho#latest) in xamarin forums)

1. git clone git@github.com:xamarin/urho.git
2. git submodule update --init
   // make sure Urho3D/Source folder is not empty
3. run 'make HoloLens'
4. open the solution and build UrhoSharp.HoloLens (Release, x86 configuration)

Doing this mostly works, but the final step results in two unresolved externals:

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl WINRT_InitGameBar(struct SDL_VideoDevice *)" (?WINRT_InitGameBar@@YAXPAUSDL_VideoDevice@@@Z)   UrhoSharp.HoloLens  C:\urho\Urho3D\Urho3D_HoloLens\UrhoSharp.HoloLens\SDL_winrtvideo.obj

and

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl WINRT_QuitGameBar(struct SDL_VideoDevice *)" (?WINRT_QuitGameBar@@YAXPAUSDL_VideoDevice@@@Z)   UrhoSharp.HoloLens  C:\urho\Urho3D\Urho3D_HoloLens\UrhoSharp.HoloLens\SDL_winrtvideo.obj

These two functions are in [this file](https://github.com/xamarin/Urho3D/blob/95151b5d59aeba4f419e0ea2e9e60170d7002bf6/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/src/video/winrt/SDL_winrtvideo.cpp).

How do I track down and/or resolve these errors?

I'm not sure how to interpret and/or address the error.

Comment: Want to add additional info. This header file contains the definitions that appear to cause the issue. https://github.com/xamarin/Urho3D/blob/95151b5d59aeba4f419e0ea2e9e60170d7002bf6/Source/ThirdParty/SDL/src/video/winrt/SDL_winrtgamebar_cpp.h

Answer (score 0):

The developer put changes into the code base and this issue no longer occurs.

Comment: Though a different issue occurs ... so still not completely clean compilation.

Comment: Additionally, the readme referenced above is now edited by the developer, but still may not be correct, as he refers to projects that don't exist in the solution.